# Load div from external file into div

Tags: javascript

To reduce the file size on my index page i have tried to load in div from another page into a div on current page using ajax, the problem is i get the entire page when i would rather just load certain div from the external file instead.

```
var login = document.getElementById('display');
login.innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="view_login.php"></object>';
```

Where display is the div i want to load in new content into.

index

```
<div id="display">Ajax content goes here</div>
```

view_login.php

```
<div id="visible">

<form action="login/login.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
<input type="submit" value="Sign in" />
</form>
</div>
```

how could i load `visible` instead of entire page with body, header and everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the load function from jquery : http://api.jquery.com/load/

Check the "Loading Page Fragments" paragraph to load a specific bloc of the page.
It will be something like `$('#display').load( "view_login.php .visible" );` in your case

Comment: im trying to reduce file size, including jquery would be the opposite. im instrested of learning raw javascript and understand how its works rather than one line solution.